# Parallel.ForEach: will one of the thread be a main thread?

Tags: .net, parallel.foreach

I invoked a `Parallel.ForEach` loop from the **Main thread**. 
My question is as follows:
"Will one of the threads created during `Parallel.ForEach` be a **Main Thread**?"

Comment: Could you define `Main thread`?

Comment: What difference will it makes to your app workflow if TPL use the thread in which your Main method is executed ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use parallel constructs like `Parallel` class it doesn't mean that new threads are created. .NET offers something called thread pool, where there are many already created threads available for any .NET application, so your app won't create any new threads whether it uses classes like `Parallel` or not.

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) `Parallel.ForEach`

> Executes a foreach (For Each  in Visual Basic) operation in which
>   iterations may run in parallel.

so it is also possible that all of the `Action`s invoked may run on the main thread, if you call something trivial the compiler may probably optimize away using even thread pool threads.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.ForEach` uses a few "branch" threads to run your actions in parallel via `ThreadPool`, and blocks the current thread (your "main thread"). It is very possible that one "branch" runs on the current thread, but it's not predicable.